# Using Excel to create a record of my paychecks

Tags: microsoft-excel

Forgive me if this is newbie question, but I am creating a excel document that records the information on my pay stubs.  I am trying to calculate the dollar amount for the hours worked during that pay period, all the while using a second table for the rate which has all of my pay increases.

Table #1 has the following fields:

> Period Beginning || Period Ending || Hours Worked || Total $  ...........

Table #2:

> Start Date  || End Date || Pay Rate

Essentially I want to figure out the Total $ using table 2, but I want to make sure that it is choosing the right rate for that time period.

Comment: this is not a programming question

Comment: @DmitryBeransky Why not? Expressing a reference with Excel's obscure functions seems interesting enough programming task to me.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky Checked FAQ; looked at the "Related questions" on the right... Not convinced at all: there are 1.6K questions tagged `excel` on Superuser, and 10K here. By the way, `haskell` has only got 4K.

Comment: You could try with PivotTable with several sources.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky -Incorrect on "because writing Excel macros is not programming" (which I find bizarre). Excel questions fall into two categories, VBA (programming which belongs at SO) and Formulae (SU).

Comment: True, but this particular question isn't a programming question. Dmitry Beransky is right (if for the wrong reasons). This is a textbook SuperUser question. @alf: Total number of Excel question is irrelevant; that may be due to any number of other factors: superuser is newer than stackoverflow, there is less traffic on superuser in general, fewer excel questions are being asked than excel-vba questions, etc. None of this makes this particular question more programming-related. Voting to close.

Comment: There are a great many textbook Excel questions on Stackoverflow. Excel seems to be widely used at a quite simple level as an output or input for programs, which makes it programming related. In addition, it seems likely that a suitable solution for this problem will include VBA.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot really be done this way, as periods defined by `Period Beginning` and `Period Ending` will not necessarily be the same as the ones defined by `Start Date` and `End Date` — which means, you need to settle for something less.

As of the actual lookup, check out [this article](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/30/range-lookup-excel/): the example on the right is a date lookup, exactly what you need. If you change the lookup formula to `INDIRECT("G"&SUMPRODUCT(--(E6:E15<=F3)*(F6:F15>=F3),ROW(E6:E15)))` and add rates to the column `G`, you'll have the lookup part done.